# Multiple Knapsack where items can't be reused and have different value for different knapsack

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a problem where:

1. There are multiple knapsack
2. There is a fixed set of items , `SuperSet` you can say
3. Every Knapsack have a `specific subset` of items
4. One item can only be put into one knapsack and can't be reused
5. Each item have different value for different knapsack
6. Weight of every item is same but value differs according to knapsack

Now I need to distribute items in a way that my final Sum of Knapsacks is the highest.

Some Additional Details:

- I'm a programmer and not an algo writer, so please pardon of I dont know some details
- Language: Any (prefer C#)
- I just need a specific algo that resolves my situation, I'll write the code myself
- Currently an alternative approach is `The Multiple Subset Sum Problem with non identical bins`, but I'm searching

I'll provide bounty once Stack Overflow allows me too to the right answer even if its before! In a very crucial fix here.

Comment: `value differs according to knapsack` - this seems like to (multiple) assignment problem

Comment: @RyanVincent nah, algorithm questions are best left without a specific language. Although the target paradigm can be useful, imperative is normally assumed.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent There is no need in specific language with `algorithm` tag.

Comment: @MBo Please explain a little

Comment: @Taran Goel Every item might be assigned to specific knapsack with given value - this is `assignment problem`. But weight limit and other factors complicate the problem.

Comment: @MBo Is there any particular algo name i can refer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem

Comment: Is the capacity of all knapsacks equal?

Comment: @LiorKogan No, it's not :/

Answer (score 3):

This is the [maximum generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem) with a specific relaxation (Weight of every item is same but value differs according to bin).

This relaxation is important: since weight of each item is same but value differs according to knapsack, you can normalize all weights to '1' by dividing the capacity of each knapsack according to the weight of its items.

Now it becomes the multiple subset-sum problem, with a slight difference: the capacity of each knapsack is different.

This problem had been studied in "[A PTAS for the Multiple Subset Sum Problem with different knapsack capacities](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019000000107)" [Caprara, Kellerer, Pferschy] 1999, where a polynomial-time (1 − ε)-approximation algorithm is given. Another approximation scheme is given in "[Approximating the 0–1 Multiple Knapsack Problem with Agent Decomposition and Market Negotiation](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-45049-1_36)" [Smolinski] 2003.

An exact algorithm is given in "[ALGORITHM 632 - A Program for the 0-1 Multiple
Knapsack Problem](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=214397)" [Martello, Toth] 1985. A Fortran (sorry...) code can be found [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/toms632/toms632.html).

Comment: I dont have access to the paper, anyother source you may refer or better any code implementation? I know I'm asking for much.:/

Comment: @TaranGoel: See my edit. That's the best I could find.

Comment: Kongan : Can you please help me with a scenario where every knapsack have different subset of allowed items?

Comment: @TaranGoel: That's the maximum generalized assignment problem where some of the weights w(item i, bin b) are infinite.

Answer (score 0):

It's a more complicated version of the Knapsack problem, which means it is NP complete, which means there is no solution that is guaranteed to be acceptably fast. On the other hand, being more complicated may make it easier to find an optimal solution.

The basic idea would go like this: You start with empty containers. As long as an item fits into the first container, you add it there. Then you add items to the second container, and so on. This gives you a solution which is likely not optimal. So you backtrack the last step and add a different item. If that doesn't find a better solution you backtrack the last two steps and so on. To save trying all kinds of combinations that aren't going to work anyway, you always try to calculate an upper bound for the value you might achieve, and stop examining further if that upper bound doesn't beat the known best solution.

When putting things into the first container, check for each item how much you gain by putting it into that container and not another one. Sort all the items by gain per weight. For example, if an item has a value of 40 in the first container, and 20 in another container, and weighs 2 units, that's a value of 10 per unit if you put it into the first container. An item that has a value of 40 in any container can be put anywhere. So you first put the items into the first container where that produces a gain (the idea is that this is likely to get you a good solution, and if you have *one* good solution then you can remove less good solutions from the search).

Don't try to make your code run fast. Try to make it easily modifiable. That's because I have no idea how well my ideas work (it's just the idea that I would start with). So you create samples, try how well the algorithm works, and then you come up with ideas how to find good solutions easier. If you keep the code easily modifiable then you can try out better ideas easily.